# Relative import error even after adding __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, packaging

This is the directory structure in a project I am working on:

```
.
├── analyx
│   ├── database.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── endpoints.py
│   ├── errors.py
│   ├── flow.py
│   ├── import_test_copy.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── metrics.py
│   ├── mkdocs.yml
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── plugins.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── endpoints.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── endpoints.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── errors.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── errors.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── flow.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── flow.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── metrics.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── metrics.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── plugins.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── plugins.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── visualize.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── visualize.py
├── docs2
│   ├── dev_docs
│   │   └── graph.md
│   ├── flow.md
│   └── index.md
├── endpoints2.py
├── flow_test_copy.py
├── __init__.py
├── metrics2.py
├── mkdocs.yml
├── plugins
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── test_plugin
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│       │   ├── models.py
│       │   └── test_plugin.cpython-38.pyc
│       └── test_plugin.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── endpoints.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── metrics.cpython-39.pyc
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── flow_test.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_dummy.py
```

As evident, I have added `__init__.py` to all the directories, so that I can import them as packages and sub packages.

The content of the file `plugins/test_plugin/test_plugin.py` starts as follows:

`from ...analyx.plugins import Plugin`

It still gives the error:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

How do I fix it? I am not very acquainted with the nuances of the Python Packaging system, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you just want `from ...plugins import Plugin`. One dot refers to `test_plugin`, two dots `plugins`, and three dots `analyx`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but still it doesn't work

Comment: You go up to the root directory, where `setup.py`, `requirements.txt` etc live (from the three dots). That is one level too far. You can't do that, and certainly shouldn't try (that is, don't put an `__init__.py` there; remove it).

Comment: You should regard `analyx` as a complete separate package from `plugins`, and import it as such: `from analyx.plugins import Plugin`. Don't use relative imports between packages, only *inside* a package.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't even notice that `test_plugin` wasn't in `analyx`. This is why *minimum* examples are important; there are for more modules than necessary to reproduce the problem in the question.

Comment: @9769953 I tried doing so, but it doesn't work as intended.